# Accessing array value in Nifi FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to access values of an array in Json using FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter

Input data:

> {"data":[["1580860800000","67.2"]],"itemid":5917,"label":"xxx","type":"stacked_element"}

Desired output

> {"data1":"1580860800000", "data2":"67.2","itemid":5917,"label":"xxx","type":"stacked_element"}

Can this be done using Nifi Expression language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter currently allows access to nested fields, please feel free to [write a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI) to add this capability or perhaps a FreeFormTextRecordPathWriter to enable the use of RecordPath expressions.

I assume if you're trying FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter, then you know there will always be two entries in the `data` array. If that's the case, since the input/output is valid JSON, if there's one object in the flowfile you can use JoltTransformJSON with the following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "0": "data1",
          "1": "data2"
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

If there is more than one JSON object in the file, you can use JoltTransformRecord with a JsonTreeReader and JsonRecordSetWriter and the above spec.

If you don't know how many elements are in the array, you can still split them up with the following spec, but note that the first element has an index of 0 not 1 (so `data0` instead of `data1`):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": "data&"
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

UpdateRecord is another option, but I believe you'd still have to know how many elements are in the array.